# Hide / Show select arrow

Tags: html, css

Despite my search I just found related subject about removing or hiding the arrow but not showing it on hover.

The goal is to hide the HTML Select Arrow for all latest major browser, Edge, Chrome and IE 11 but showing it when mouse hover.

Right now I've been able to make it work in IE 11 perfectly with the following code however it's not working fine in Chrome and Edge.  Any insight on what to change or add in this code to make it cross browser ?

```css
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

select:hover {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  -moz-appearance: menulist;
}
select:hover::-ms-expand {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Marc Roussel</option>
    <option>Gilles Lavoie</option>
    <option>Roger Maheu</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-webkit-appearance: menulist`.
or `appearance: none` for modern browsers:

See http://trentwalton.com/2010/07/14/css-webkit-appearance/ for the whole list.

[IMO, from a user point of view, it's a strange requirement to turn something standard and "normal" to something specific and surprising]

Comment: This is 50% working.  Why Chrome changes the whole textbox part while other browser keep the style ?  Everything should be the same in all major browser.

This requirement is for having this in a grid.  You don't want to have this arrow for all rows of the column having this control

Comment: `-webkit-` rules apply only to webkit browsers (Opeara, Chrome). Others won't be impacted. I don't have Edge here, so I cannot check that browser. I wouldn't mind having such grid, further more knowing that mobile/tablet do not display the arrow on by devices.

Comment: Yes indeed this is something I'm aware about -webkit-

Another thing to note is that in IE 11 which it is working just fine, when the select is clicked and then we click elsewhere in the document, the arrow revert to hidden which is perfect but in Edge the menulist solution makes the arrow stays after clicking elsewhere

Comment: Another bad thing about menulist and I think it's about that, when clicking the select in Chrome and clicking elsewhere, the list remains visible that is not desirable.

Comment: @MarcRoussel Old comment-answer but what you describe is then a *browser* issue that you should send to Chrome in there issuetracker. Browsers (at least, Firefox) probably have a UX team that will status on this, and they will implement your idea for *the whole world* to enjoy if that's for a better UX. You should not then spend time "complexively fixing" this on your single website, but instead should report it to appropriate browser team.

Comment: It seems working pretty fine now with all major browser.  I just tested.  Thanx for the comment